# Outlook 2010 - Only receive NEW emails

Tags: windows, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2010

Is there a way to only receive new emails. That is, emails received by the mail server past a certain point? I'm terribly unorganized with my emails and I have a huge repository of emails that I don't need to be on outlook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately if the server was pop and the option of "leave message on server" you will have to re download all the emails.Easiest way to sort is to download all the messages and sort using date. Then anything older than "1 year" (for example) you can just select all in that range and delete

Answer (score 0):

You can at least get it to only download the headers, then delete the old messages (and make sure your settings are such that this will actually delete the copy on the server), then switch to download everything and you should be good to go forward